# Hive vs Spark in production environments

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, hiveql

I am looking for use cases of Hive vs Spark in actual production environments. Do the 2 technologies coexist in a production environment? If yes, what kind of transformation are fine through HiveQL  and what cases are handled through SparkSQL?

Comment: Impala or Presto are often used instead of Hive (Presto being easier to install)

Answer (score 0):

From our experience we use:

1. Spark for ETL
2. Hive for Analytical processing.

Though one thing to take into account - is what is underneath Hive. For example Hive on Tez will be faster than spark for analytics. But if Hive will be on MapReduce - it's better to use Spark for analytics.

Comment: What kind of transformation are generally done in Hive. I am from a Data warehousing background and we generally do very lengthy and cumbersome ETL works through GUI based tools. Is it possible/recommend to do so much cumbersome ETL work through Hive. Won't the development efforts be too long since many queries would need to be hand written instead of a GUI tool handling it?

Comment: Generally we do: Data injection, Data validation/cleaning, incremental loading, standardization, filtering using Spark. In Hive we do queries that provides data for business users and visualization. From my experience - GUI tools are always slower than IDE/handwriting for experienced employees. Anyway noone prohibits to use GUI tools for architecturing queries and then implement them in Spark or SQL code.